# Server less Group Messaging (chating) Xmpp

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I Want to Implement Group Messaging (chatting) without associating server(Peer to Peer chatting)

Although connections are established by ejabberd server.I am able to do it one to one chat but didn't got success in group messaging.

Does anyone has idea how to implement this feature ?

Comment: @NullByte is correct, but what do you mean by "without associating server"?

Answer (score 2):

Your Looking for MultiChatUser(MUC), if your using aSmack or Smack for chatting peer to peer then you can surly do group chat using MUC, refer below link for MUC chat

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html

Hope this helps you!